# Complete rails json API example with Rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rspec, bdd

I'm looking for a good example repository of a Rails 3 project that implements a JSON API and has included RSpec tests. A full tutorial would be great but I'd settle for just a well commented example.

Comment: Not to promote myself too much, but I wrote a tutorial on creating an oauth2 based API, however some general concepts will still apply, and there are a couple specs in there you can take a look at.  https://github.com/Gazler/Oauth2-Tutorial

Comment: are there any up to date tutorials with rails 3.2 available? Because the repo is over 2 years old, maybe there are better solutions now, or some concepts has changed

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yehuda Katz and Ryan Bigg's excellent upcoming book, [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz/), has a chapter on building a test-driven JSON API on top of the example application that runs through the entire book.

While I strongly recommend buying a copy of the beta edition of the book, the code for the sample application, Ticketee, is open source and can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee). In particular, everything API-related is namespaced under `/app/controllers/api` and you can find plenty of RSpec tests in `/spec/api`.

I was in your same position a couple of months ago when I was having to write a JSON API for an iPhone app so I'm well aware of the lack of good, test-driven, relevant tutorials online. Lucky for me I found out about the book and it turned out to be an absolute life saver.

Comment: Rails 3 in Action is certainly a well written book for TDD, has a very nice API section.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation - I'm going to check it out.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example of a spec that posts JSON to a controller.

Comment: @z5h: Really? Section 13.1.6 ("Creating projects") of Rails 3 in Action shows an example of POSTing to an API endpoint and passing some JSON parameters to create a new database record.

Comment: @LeoCassarani, I meant the repo, not the book.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/blob/master/spec/api/v1/projects_spec.rb#L44) is what I was specifically referring to.

Comment: In the book the author recommends to create the path `/spec/apis/v1/` in its **plural** version as mentioned in chapter 13.1.1 on page 351. In the [Ticketee example](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/tree/master/spec/api/v1) however the **singular path** `/spec/api/v1/` is used. Does this affect any tests?

Comment: I deployed a Rails engine (packed as a gem) that is really useful to debug APIs on rails. You just have to mount the engine and go to the url that you specified, i.e. “localhost:3000/api_explorer” to see it. It’s a way of documenting an API also, reading the webservices specification from a file.
The gem is named ‘api_explorer’ and the repo is http://www.github.com/toptierlabs/api_explorer
Any comments or help improving the api is welcome. :)

Answer (score 9):

[RubyGems.org](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org) is open source and has a great example of an API

Answer (score 0):

Can't necessarily answer the api example, but I can definitely vouch for the API testing of a rails 3 app in processes.

Here you go: whitneytaylorimura.wordpress.com

It has a full example using Cucumber, Rspec, & FactoryGirl to create your objects (with DatabaseCleaner to clean them up).